# Create 3D triangulated mesh from scratch

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, mesh, triangulation, delaunay

What I am trying to do is to create a 3D triangulated mesh that can be parsed into a .vtk or .stl file for use in 3D printing application. Right now I am stuck with the creation of the triangle mesh. The geometry I want to create are basically three dimensional sine waves that have a certain thickness and intersect each other. So far I got one sine wave. Here's a MWE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage
import scipy.spatial

# create empty 3d array
array = np.zeros((100, 100, 100))

# create 3D sine wave in empty array
strut = np.sin(np.linspace(1, 10, 100))*12
for k in enumerate(strut):
    y_shift = int(np.round(strut[k[0]]))
    array[k, 50 + y_shift, 50] = 1

pattern = np.ones((4, 4, 4))

# convolve the array with the pattern / apply thickness
conv_array = ndimage.convolve(array, pattern)

# create list with data coordinates from convolved array
data = list()
for j in range(conv_array.shape[0]):
    for k in range(conv_array.shape[1]):
        for l in range(conv_array.shape[2]):
            if conv_array[j, k, l] != 0:
                data.append([j, k, l])

data = np.asarray(data)

tri = scipy.spatial.Delaunay(data)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")
ax.hold(True)
ax.plot_trisurf(data[:, 0], data[:, 1], data[:, 2], triangles=tri.simplices)
plt.show()
```

What it does: I create an empty array which I fill with a sine wave represented by ones. I convolve that array with a rectangular array of a defined size, which gives me a thicker sine wave in space. Then the array gets converted into coordinate form so that it can be triangulated using Delaunay triangulation. What I get is this:

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlSrZ.png)

As you can see the triangulation kinda worked, but it fills the space between the sine wave amplitudes. Is there a way to remove the filled spaced? Or prevent it from doing them in the first place? The sine wave also looks wrong at the ends and I am not sure why. Is this even the best method to achieve want I am trying to do?

The parsing to a .vtk file should not present a problem, but I need a clean structure first. Thanks in advance for any kind of help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got something very close to what I want. In case someone is interested in the answer:

Instead of going with the point cloud approach I dug myself into VTK (which is a pain to learn, but has a lot of functionality) with python.

My algorithm is basically this:

1. Approximate the sine wave as a simple triangular wave first.
2. Feed the x, y and z coordinates of the wave into a vtkPoints object
3. Use vtkParametricSpline to get a smooth wave
4. vtkSplineFilter to have control over the smoothness of the wave
5. vtkTubeFilter to create a volume from the line
6. vtkTriangleFilter for meshing
7. vtkSTLWriter

Answer (score 1):

I would not reinvent the wheel and do all that on my own. Rather than that, use python-vtk and paraview (which is a post-processing application for 3D data) to do the triangulation for you. "Just" create the points and do the rest in that application.

I don't know much about 3D printing, but I know my fair share about STL and VTK. It is a pain to do manually and the VTK library has [has some nice Python examples](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Python) and a dedicated [STLWriter](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Python/STLWriter). You *just* need to wrap your head around the workflow of VTK and how it manages things internally. This is where [paraview](http://paraview.org/) comes in quite handy. It enables you to record your actions that you do in the GUI and displays them and displays them *in Python*. This is great to learn the way it works internally.

Comment: Thanks for your insight! I thought about using VTK before, but couldn't quite wrap my head around how to create the geometry I want. But what you're basically saying is, that my way of creating the point cloud is okay, but the triangulation is better handled by VTK?

Comment: I haven't studied your method in depth, to be honest. But i know for a fact that there are people in the scientific computing community that use VTK and paraview (which is entirely build upon VTK) to visualize point clouds of orders of magnitudes larger than yours and do way more complex things with it than triangulation. I would just give it a go, since it is all there ready to be used and you don't have to reimplement the wheel. If it doesn't work, you can fall back regardless. The triangulation works quite nicely in VTK. Maybe you have to seperate the pointclouds into different inputs.

Comment: Okay, I will give VTK a go. If I make any progress I will update my post and mark your post as the answer.